# Need help identifying this vine/berries

Tags: vines

I have this vine growing in my yard in Northern Indiana but since there are three leaves I chose to just stay away from it. I would appreciate help in identifying these tempting berries

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert, but it looks like a Dewberry to me. Dewberries look like blackberries but they don't always have the same conic shape and are smaller. Here's a link to a website with a few pictures: http://www.redhousegarden.com/2014/08/dewberries.html?m=1 . It's about the right time for dewberries to ripen too.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Even though I don't see any thorns in your pictures, I'm pretty sure those are wild (or feral?) blackberries. Hate to tell a stranger, long-distance, that something is edible, but maybe you can convince yourself by smelling some crushed ones??? Or better yet, ask a neighbor to be sure.

Comment: I don't think those are blackberries; the wild ones I used to harvest were much bigger and on canes that were 4-8 feet long, with wicked thorns. These berries look to be too small and are on shorter canes. They look more like blackcaps (wild black raspberries) than blackberries, although the drupes are looser than in blackcaps that I've eaten. The plants do appear to be in the Rubus (raspberry) genus, however.

Comment: Lorel I am cracking up!  "Ask a neighbor to be sure"...really?  Snorting!!  No thorns excellent point this could be an escaped thornless bramble berry? More like boysenberry, marionberry?  Oh, and there is a  Teaberry...these berries could be hampered, retarded, too little light?